# Fiber-complete category are invariant under equivalence

Tags: category-theory

A concrete category $(C,U)$ is said to be fiber-complete if any of its fiber by U is a complete lattice. Is such a notion invariant by equivalence of categories?

Comment: I guess it depends on whether the equivalence of categories is fibered, or in other words if it commutes with the functors to $\sf Set$.

Comment: So in general the property of being fiber-complete is non-invariant. I recall that a concrete category is a category together with a faithful functor to Set. Fiber-complete means that $U^{-1}(X)$ is a complete lattice for any $X \in Set$.

Comment: It is invariant under the only sensible choice of equivalence between concrete categories, which is one that commutes with the forgetful functors, as fosco already pointed out.

Comment: A fibered equivalence induces equivalences between the fibers; equivalences of posets are isomorphisms, and the property of being a complete lattice is invariant under isomorphism.

Comment: Reading The Joy of Cats, I found some interesting things: first, in general even though it makes sense to say that two concrete categories over $Set$ are concretely isomorphic, it makes little sense to say that they are concretely equivalent since the relation between concrete categories of being concretely equivalent is not symmetric. So, in our discussion, we must replace equivalence with isomorphism. Next, the fibers are only preordered sets, unless $U$ is amnestic (though usually forgetful functors are). If we are in the previous case, fosco's argument works.

Comment: Ah, I guess there is a misunderstanding about how to define a poset. I (and I guess fosco as well) define a poset in the equivalence-invariant way, i.e. as a category that is equivalent to a poset. If you chose a stricter approach, then of course the situation is different.